# Image width is not showing properly in Card of Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make layout using *Jetpack Compose*.

I want to show an **Image** and a **Text** in each **Card**, stacked **vertically** using *Column widget*

I could successfully wrote the code using *Composable function* but I am getting issues in last Card like below mentioned:

- The Image **width** is not FULL
- The TextView **is not showing** below Image

Code :

```
    @Composable
fun Dashboard(name1: String, name2: String, name3: String) {
    Column(
        modifier =
        Modifier.background(color = Color(0, 255, 0, 255))
    ) {
        Card() {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img1),
                    contentDescription = "Image 1")
                Text(text = name1)
            }
        }
        Card() {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img2),
                    contentDescription = "Image 2")
                Text(text = name2)
            }
        }
        Card() {
            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img2),
                    contentDescription = "Image 3")
                Text(text = name3)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output :
[image]

The Last Card's image (img2) is same as middle Card's image but is giving issue at last index only

Can anyone help what is wrong in my Composable Function?

**Reference**:

I am following tutorials of The Hyper Coder community [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_F2wzV45ZQ)

Comment: The code should work. Which version of compose are you using?

Comment: my compose version is `1.0.0-beta01`

Comment: Try with beta03

Comment: ok will try and let you know, thanks

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I tried, but same problem with `beta03`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on Jetpack Compose Beta 3.
By default `Column { }` is not scroll able, It lays out the contents in the available space on the screen.

So whats happening with your last image is, its shirking its height which resulted in shirking its width to maintain the aspect ratio. This resulted in the green background to show up. So making your top `Column { }` scrollable should fix this.

```
Column(
    modifier =  Modifier
    .background(color = Color(0, 255, 0, 255))
    .verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState(0))
) {
    Card { ... }
    Card { ... }
    Card { ... }
  }
```

**UPDATE:** Better solution to handle such scenarios is by using `LazyColum` which is much better in performance to handle such a specific use case

```
@Composable
fun Dashboard(images: List<ImageData>) {
  LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.background(color = Color(0, 255, 0, 255))
  ) {
    images.forEach {
      item { ImageCard(image = it) }
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun ImageCard(image: ImageData) {
  Card {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
      Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = image.drawable),
        contentDescription = image.text
      )
      Text(text = image.text)
    }
  }
}

val images = listOf(
  ImageData("Image 1", R.drawable.img1),
  ImageData("Image 2", R.drawable.img2),
  ImageData("Image 3", R.drawable.img2)
)

data class ImageData(
  val text: String,
  @DrawableRes val drawable: Int
)
```

Comment: This fixed the problem as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Does this  mean we need to add `verticalScroll(state = rememberScrollState(0))` at each time where we need vertical scrolling? Scrolling won't work without this?

Comment: you can make your own copy of `Column`with name `ScrollableColumn` and make it scrollable with modifier always and use that instead. But I think LazyColum with items is better fit and cleaner. Updated the answer to include that.